# OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion Finder sidebar/Favorites: add MyComputer shortcut?

Tags: macos, finder

How can I add a shortcut to "MyComputer"/"This Mac" (container of all drives) to the Finder.app sidebar (section: "Favorites), please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under **Finder's Preferences / Sidebar / Devices** check your computer's name.